# Using Nexmo Verify to Login to a Ruby Sinatra App

Tags: ruby, security, sinatra, vonage

I have found a [ruby on rails 2fa nexmo verify tutorial](https://www.nexmo.com/blog/2016/06/07/two-factor-authentication-2fa-ruby-rails-devise-nexmo-verify/) but some of it doesn't work on Sinatra because the frameworks have some differences and it doesn't fit what I'm making. Can anyone help me out or lead me in the path of using [Nexmo Verify](https://www.nexmo.com/products/verify/) in my Sinatra app?

```
post "/" do
  client = Nexmo::Client.new(key: 'mykey', secret: 'mysecret')
  response = client.send_verification_request(number   params[:phonenumber], brand: 'OpenINC')
  if response['status'] == '0'
    erb :code
  else
    erb :error
  end
end

get'/code' do
  erb :code
end

post '/code' do
  client = Nexmo::Client.new(key: 'mykey', secret: 'mysecret')
  response = client.check_verification_request(code: '1234', request_id: '00e6c3377e5348cdaf567e1417c707a5')

  if response['status'] == '0'
    erb :start
  else
    erb :error
  end
end
```

Where it says mykey and mysecret I put my key and secret but just didn't want to put my actual key and secret on Stack OverFlow

Comment: what exactly are you having trouble with? Can you show some code you've tried to write?

Comment: Hi @maxpleaner here is what's happening: I got it to work where it sends the user a verification code. I am having trouble at the part where the user enters the code received on their phone and from there tells the user is logged in and their count is initialized. This is the code: github.com/openinc/openinc

Comment: You seem to be new to StackOverflow, so it's understandable, but it's important to to include actual code snippets with your question, not in a Github repo / screenshot / tutorial. People are more eager to answer questions if they're narrowed down.

Comment: can you post it in the question text area with proper formatting? Highlight it and type control+k to format a code block.

Comment: just did @maxpleaner

Comment: ok, now what's not working?

Comment: @maxpleaner what is happening now is that the user is getting the code and the verify page is showing up. so far the verify has not worked. I am trying to get it so that you get the code, put the code in a form to verify it and that is what logs in the user, so something from that number or code will have to be extracted to tell the web app or database that a user is signed in and now created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code above, and that in [the repo](https://github.com/OpenInc/openinc/tree/b15dc5feb37f14a79260c9924e8bae3eece7055b), the problem is simply that the `request_id` and `code` values are hard-coded.

If you:

1. Store the `request_id` from the response to the `response = client.send_verification_request(number: params[:phonenumber], brand: 'OpenINC')` call e.g. `session[:request_id] = response['request_id']`
2. Get the code that the user submits in the `post /code` route e.g. `code = params[:code]`
3. Retrieve the `request_id` from the `session` in the `post /code` route e.g. `request_id = session[:request_id]`
4. Use the `code` and `request_id` when checking the verification request e.g. `check_verification_request(code: code, request_id: request_id)

Then the code will work.

Full basic example:

```
post "/" do
  client = Nexmo::Client.new(key: 'mykey', secret: 'mysecret')
  response = client.send_verification_request(number: params[:phonenumber], brand: 'OpenINC')

  # 1. Store request_id
  session[:request_id] = response['request_id']

  if response['status'] == '0'
    erb :code
  else
    erb :error
  end
end

get'/code' do
  erb :code
end

post '/code' do
  # 2. Get the user verification code
  code = params[:code]

  # 3. Retrieve the request_id
  request_id = session[:request_id]

  client = Nexmo::Client.new(key: 'mykey', secret: 'mysecret')

  # 4. Use the code and request_id
  response = client.check_verification_request(code: code, request_id: request_id)

  if response['status'] == '0'
    erb :start
  else
    erb :error
   end
end
```

I've also submitted a PR against your repo [here](https://github.com/OpenInc/openinc/pull/5) with [this commit](https://github.com/OpenInc/openinc/commit/69af5b11be2903097a155f520bf5768e2c5c53ec) containing the main details.

Comment: Thanks again so much!!